# How to set the global disbaledDate property for DatePicker component in React(TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

The Questions is: How to set the global `disbaledDate` property for DatePicker component in React(TypeScript)?
I want to set all the DatePicker component can't select the date **before** 9999/12/31.

I try to package the DatePicker as a React Component, but `const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;` doesn't work

————————————

That is the Detail of my project:
First I use the DayJs to replace the **Moment.js** like this:

```
// DatePicker.tsx
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs';
import generatePicker from 'antd/es/date-picker/generatePicker';
import 'antd/es/date-picker/style/index';
export const DatePicker = generatePicker<Dayjs>(dayjsGenerateConfig);
```

Then I use the DatePicker and RangePicker in other components like this:

```
// testPage.tsx
import DatePicker from '../common/DatePicker.tsx';
...
export function testPage(props: Props) {
   const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
   return <>
             <DatePicker>
             <RangePicker>
          </>
}
```

So, How Can I set the global `disbaledDate` property for DatePicker without change any code in file **testPage.tsx** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// DatePicker.tsx
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs';
import generatePicker from 'antd/es/date-picker/generatePicker';
import 'antd/es/date-picker/style/index';

const DatePicker = generatePicker<Dayjs>(dayjsGenerateConfig);

DatePicker.defaultProps = {
  disabledDate: (date) => true,
};

export default DatePicker;
```